# C#: custom control calls click handler every other click (winform, not ASP)

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, mouseevent

I have written a custom control in C# (inherited from Forms.Control) and it seems to working fine, but if you press the button fast enough a problem occurs: only every other click will call the click event handler.  This doesn't happen if you don't press it fast (less than once a second).  The mouseUp and mouseDown handlers always get called no matter how fast you click the button.

Of course doesn't happen with the canned winform button.

I cannot use the canned button because I'm writing an application for the .net compact framework, so I need a custom control in order to make the UI more presentable.  Also, I tested out my code on the full version of the .net framework, and I still have the same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Is your custom control being base off of an usercontrol or another control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are clicking rapidly enough, you are getting into [`DoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx) territory.

According to above MSDN Page the order of events are:

The following series of events is raised by the control when such a user action takes place:

1. MouseDown event.
2. Click event.
3. MouseClick event.
4. MouseUp event.
5. MouseDown event.
6. DoubleClick event.
7. MouseDoubleClick event.
8. MouseUp event

If you will notice there is only one `Click` event per `DoubleClick`

---

For a way to disable it try looking at this MSDN Page discussing [ControlStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx).

From above link:

> **StandardClick** -- If true, the control implements the standard Click behavior.
>   **StandardDoubleClick** -- If true, the control implements the standard DoubleClick behavior. This style is ignored if the StandardClick bit is not set to true.

So try this in your controls constructor or load event:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick, true );
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false);
```

Since `SetStyle` does not appear to be in the Compact Framework you could add a DoublClick Event and have it trigger the Click event Programmically like this.

```
YourClickEvent(sender, new MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left,1,0,0,0));
```

Comment: @GeorgeSummer You are welcome it appears that the option that I gave using SetStyles is not available in the Compact Framework, I have added another option that should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you click your control fast enough, it calls double click rather than click.
So, you should do something like this in your click function:

```
{
    control.Enabled = false; 
    ......
    control.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this tomorrow morning.